# Get Value input Yii

Tags: count, yii, rows

How do I pass a form value to the controller, "actionCreate function ()" specifically. Exemplifying.
I have the following code in the form:

```
<tbody class="templateTarget">
<php foreach ($ items as $ i => $ item):?>
<tr class="templateContent">
<td>
<php echo $ form-> textField ($ item, "[$ i] name", array ('style' => 'width: 100px'));?>
</ td>
<td>
<php echo $ form-> textField ($ item, "[$ i] description ', array (' style '=>' width: 100px '));?>
</td>
<td>
<input type = "hidden" class = "rowIndex" value = "<? php echo $i;?>" />
<div class="remove"> <php echo Yii:: t ('wm', 'Remove');?>
</ td>
</tr>
<php endforeach;?>
```

As a step in the variable $ i to "actionCreate ()", this value need to know how many rows were created.

Help me!

Answer (score 0):

This is done using [tabular input](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.table)

Comment: With the tabular can not get the value that is input in this case the variable $ i.<p></p>

Does anyone know how to help me in this problem?

Comment: You might need to elaborate. I cant quiet understand your problem.

Comment: I have a form where I use to create tabular input multiple rows where I have a button to add a new line, I need to know how many rows were filled by this is that the problem presented above. Well if you can pass the value of the variable $ i help me a lot.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are using tabular input you could just count the rows.

count($_POST["Model"]["name"]);